# Certain files not being instrumented for code coverage using nyc (istanbul)

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I'm experiencing an issue where some of my files are not being included in my nyc test coverage report.

I want all my files to be included in my test coverage report even if they have 0% of their lines run by tests. So I included the flag "--all=true" in my test-cov script:

[image: test-cov npm script]

This worked to get most of my files to show up in the report, but there are still a few files that are missing. Through experimenting I found that for these missing files, there is an issue that is preventing them from being included whenever they use types. Whenever types are used in these specific files, they ***don't show up*** in the report; but if I remove the types then they ***do*** start to show up in the report.

For example in this .ts file when ": any" (the only type used in this file) is used on a function param, the file doesn't show up in the report, but when I take out ": any" it does show up.

[image: :any params]

But it's also interesting because we use types in many of the other files that are being successfully covered, so I'm not sure why the types in these files specifically would cause them not to be instrumented/covered:

Has anybody seen an issue like this before? Would appreciate any help

Comment: Bumping this to see if anyone can help!

Comment: Had a similar problem. For me, t helped to update nyc from version 12 to version 15.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but check your npm version. I was seeing the same thing in one environment but not in another. The problem started early November. Turns out the failing environment installed npm@latest, so it was getting npm v9. Th working environment is using npm v8. This is what broke the coverage reports: npm version 9.